# Рисование мышкой в PictureBox

Tags: wpf, winforms

Ребята, кто знает вкратце код рисования мышкой на PictureBox?

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю, PictureBox служит только для отображения картинок, а не рисования;
для рукописного ввода/рисования служит класс InkPresenter.
Код XAML:

```
<Canvas>
    <TextBlock Text="InkPresenter Control" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="50,30,0,0" />
    <Rectangle Height="500" Width="500" Margin="50,50,0,0" Stroke="Black" />
    <InkPresenter x:Name="MyIP" Height="500" Width="500"
        Margin="50,50,0,0"
        MouseLeftButtonDown="MyIP_MouseLeftButtonDown" 
        LostMouseCapture="MyIP_LostMouseCapture" 
        MouseMove="MyIP_MouseMove" 
        Background="Transparent" Opacity="1" />
</Canvas>
```

Код cs:

```
public Page()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SetBoundary();
}
Stroke NewStroke;

// A new stroke object named MyStroke is created. 
// MyStroke is added to the StrokeCollection of the InkPresenter named MyIP
private void MyIP_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    MyIP.CaptureMouse();
    StylusPointCollection MyStylusPointCollection = new StylusPointCollection();
    MyStylusPointCollection.Add(e.StylusDevice.GetStylusPoints(MyIP));
    NewStroke = new Stroke(MyStylusPointCollection);
    MyIP.Strokes.Add(NewStroke);
}

//  StylusPoint objects are collected from the MouseEventArgs and added to MyStroke. 
private void MyIP_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (NewStroke != null)
        NewStroke.StylusPoints.Add(e.StylusDevice.GetStylusPoints(MyIP));
}

//  MyStroke is completed
private void MyIP_LostMouseCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    NewStroke = null;        
}

//  Set the Clip property of the inkpresenter so that the strokes
//  are contained within the boundary of the inkpresenter
private void SetBoundary()
{
    RectangleGeometry MyRectangleGeometry = new RectangleGeometry();
    MyRectangleGeometry.Rect = new Rect(0, 0, MyIP.ActualWidth, MyIP.ActualHeight);
    MyIP.Clip = MyRectangleGeometry;
}
```

Comment: вот пример выполнения на Silverlight: http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/Silverlight/SampleBrowser/index.htm#/?sref=InkPresenterSnippet

Answer (score 1):

Процесс рисования (например, прямой линии) состоит из трех основных действий:

- Выбрать точку начала линии и нажать на кнопку мыши.
- Не отпуская кнопку мыши, протянуть линию до конечной точки, рисуя фигуру до каждой текущей точки и стирая старую фигуру.
- При отпускании кнопки мыши зафиксировать конечную точку мыши.

Протащить линию до конечной точки по прямой практически невозможно. При протаскивании линия рисуется до каждой текущей точки, поэтому если не стирать промежуточные линии, то получится веер линий. Для обеспечения циклического процесса стирания линий в языке C# имеется событие Paint (Рисование). В обработчике этого события вызывается подпрограмма Invalidate для стирания старой и прорисовки текущей линии. Но эта подпрограмма стирает все, что имеется на экране. Поэтому нарисовать таким способом более одной фигуры нельзя (при протяжке новой фигуры будет стерта старая фигура).

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
// Здесь вставляют объявления переменных
```

В этих объявлениях выполнена инициализация:

- Режим рисования выключен.
- Фигура для рисования «Линия».
- Перо черное.
- Ширина линии 1 пиксель

Далее:

1. В обработчике события Mouse Down запишите следующие операторы (сначала объявление нового пера, поскольку параметры пера могли быть изменены перед рисованием новой фигуры):

   ```
   mypen = new Pen(color, width);
   drag = true;        // Включение режима рисования
   pBeg = e.Location;  // Фиксация координат нажатия на кнопку мыши
   ```
2. В обработчике события Mouse Move запишите следующие операторы:

   ```
   if (drag)           // Если режим рисования включен
   {
     pEnd = e.Location; // Фиксация координат текущего положения мыши
   }
   ```
3. В обработчике события Mouse Up запишите следующие операторы:

   ```
   if (drag)               // Если режим рисования включен
   {
     drag = false;         // Выключить режим рисования
     pEnd = e.Location;    // Фиксация текущих координат мыши
   }
   ```
4. В обработчике события pictureBox1_Paint запишите следующие операторы.

   ```
   pictureBox1.Invalidate();   // Стирание нарисованного
   e.Graphics.DrawLine(mypen, pBeg, pEnd);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать изображение, и по событиям мышки из PictureBox его изменять, и после обработки события отображать в нем полученное изображение.

Answer (score 0):

Сделай 3 события для PictureBox'a
**Mouse_Down**
**Mouse_Move**
**Mouse_Up**
В самом начале напиши код
    bool paint = false;
    Graphics g;

В **Mouse_Down**

```
paint = true;
```

В **Mouse_Up**

```
paint = false;
```

В **Mouse_Move**

```
if(paint)
{
SolidBrush s = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
s.FillEcplise(s, e.X, e.Y, 10, 10)
}
```